# Bazel build :protobuf does not build runtime libraries / headers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to follow the steps [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/README.md) for building the protoc and protobuf runtime files. I am running on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Running bazel build :protoc will build the protoc compiler but I am not sure what, if anything :protobuf is doing. I am expecting a "dist_files" or something where I have a folder which contains the header files needed for building my c++ project as well as a static (or dynamic) library to link to and the .proto files for the standard. If one looks at the output of `apt-file list libprotobuf-dev`, you can see:

```
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/any.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/any.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/any.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/api.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/api.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/arena.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/arena_impl.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/duration.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/duration.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/empty.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/empty.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/extension_set.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/extension_set_inl.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/has_bits.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/implicit_weak_message.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/io_win32.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/printer.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/strtod.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_entry.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_entry_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_field.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_field_inl.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_field_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/message.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/metadata.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/parse_context.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/port.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/port_def.inc
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/port_undef.inc
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/reflection.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/service.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/source_context.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/source_context.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/struct.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/struct.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/callback.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/casts.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/fastmem.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/hash.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/logging.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/macros.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/map_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/mutex.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/platform_macros.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/status.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/stl_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/template_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/text_format.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/type.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/type.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/field_comparator.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/field_mask_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/json_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/message_differencer.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/time_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/wire_format.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.h
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/include/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.a
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.a
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/protobuf-lite.pc
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/protobuf.pc
libprotobuf-dev: /usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-dev
```

How do I create a directory of headers I can point my build to as well as the necessary .a file to link to and proto files to use. I can see the headers in the src/google/protobuf folder but that is not really an install folder and it doesn't help since I don't have a static file to link to.

Thanks
Lee

PS: If you can only create an install dir via cmake ... they should really say that